# How to recode categorical data into string values in R

Tags: r, plyr

I want to recode my categorical values into string but I am getting an error.
I have tried with below code:

```
A$V2 <- revalue(A$V1, c("1"="Want Know", "2"="Need Help")
```

Error:

> x is not a factor or a character vector

Comment: `A$V2 <- revalue(factor(A$V1), c("1"="Want Know", "2"="Need Help")` **???**

Comment: i have  convert it into factor but now i am getting error like .Error in mapvalues(x, from = names(replace), to = replace, warn_missing = warn_missing) : 
  `from` and `to` vectors are not the same length.

Comment: we can help you If you post part of the data you're working on. Type `dput(head(YOURDATA))` into R-Console, copy result here!

Comment: Try with `dplyr::recode` rather than `plyr::revalue`. Assuming (from the error you get) that you have a numeric vector `V1 <- c(1, 2)`, that would be: `V2 <- recode(V1, "1" = "want know", "2" = "need help")`

Comment: `A$V2 <- revalue(as.character(A$V1), c("1" = "Want Know", "2" = "Need Help"))`?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below the code which recodes numerical factor into a character vector with the usage of `revalue` function of `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)

foo <- factor(c(1, 2, 1, 2))
foo
# [1] 1 2 1 2
# Levels: 1 2
bar <- c("Want Know", "Need Help")
names(bar) <- 1:2
res <- as.character(revalue(foo, replace = bar))
res             
# [1] "Want Know" "Need Help" "Want Know" "Need Help"
```